# Launch application and tracking its status on one Windows machine using other connected via LAN

Tags: java, ssh, windows-shell

I want to be able to communicate between two machines that are running Windows. 
I want to be able to launch an application from one machine and then on another view its status as it runs.

Could anyone please help me with what technologies I can use?

I have done some research and found out that **SSH** can be used, but I am unsure of how to use it.
I would like to be able to use **Java** for it, if possible. If not, please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, You can use RMi in this case.

```
The Java RMI system allows an object running in one Java Virtual Machine (VM) to invoke methods on an object running in another Java VM. RMI provides for remote communication between programs written in the Java programming language via the Java Remote Method Protocol (JRMP).
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt reply. :D
Also, to communicate, don't I need to use http??
as the two machines can communicate using http only??

Comment: RMI spec allows http as well using Http tunneling http://www.cs.swan.ac.uk/~csneal/InternetComputing/Tunnelling.html